# How can i add different exercises to my workout classes c# forms

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I'm doing a c# forms app for gym workout administration. I have 2 classes: workout and clients.

Clients can have different workouts and workouts can have different exercises, my doubt is how I can add different exercises to my workout classes, because I can have a workout with 5 exercises or with 1, it's a value that is always changing because each client has different needs.

```cs
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ex_geral.add_ex(textBox_ex.Text);
    lista_exer.Add(ex_geral);
    
    foreach (exercisios_gerais ex in lista_exer)
    {
        listBox_ex.Items.Add(ex.devolve_ex());
    }
}
```

Now I just need to add an exercise to a workout, but I can't have a number of exercises set, because it's a value that is always changing depending on the client needs.

Comment: Can you show how your exercise data is stored within a workout?

Comment: It sounds like you should have an `Exercise` class and your `Workout` class should have an `Exercises` property of type `List<Exercise>`. You then add an exercise to a workout by call `myWorkout.Exercises.Add(myExercise)`. The UI should be just for user interaction. The actual data should be in data structures under that.

Comment: I have made an answer. If you accept it, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue. Please let me know if there is any problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `lista_exer` to store the data entered from the textbox.

Then traverse `lista_exer` and pass the traversed data into `listBox`.

Code show as below:

```
namespace WinFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> lista_exer = new List<string>();
            lista_exer.Add(textBox_ex.Text.ToString());
            foreach (string ex in lista_exer)
            {
                listBox_ex.Items.Add(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]